# Управление сессиями Jetty Webscoket Server

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

В общем задача, при получении одним из `webscoket'ов`  сообщения, переслать это сообщение остальным подключенным `websocket'ам`. Использую jetty-9.2.20.v20161216.

Вот так инициализирую сервер.

```
JettyWSServer websocketServer = new JettyWSServer("localhost", 8000, new MySocketHandler(), new QueuedThreadPool(128));

public <T extends WebSocketHandler> JettyWSServer(String hostName, int port, T webscoketHandler, QueuedThreadPool threadPool) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.port = port;
    this.handler = webscoketHandler;
    this.threadPool = threadPool;
    this.socket = null;

    //create server
    this.server = new Server(this.threadPool);

    //set connector
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setHost(this.hostName);
    connector.setPort(this.port);
    this.server.addConnector(connector);

    //set handler
    this.server.setHandler(this.handler);

    //set listener
    setLifecycleListener();
}
```

**MySocketHandler.java**

```
public class MySocketHandler extends WebSocketHandler {

    private final String TAG = MySocketHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private MySocketCreator creator;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory webSocketServletFactory) {
        this.creator = new MySocketCreator();
        webSocketServletFactory.setCreator(this.creator);
    }


    public Set<ServerSocket> getSockets(){
        return this.creator.getSockets();
    }
}
```

**MySocketCreator.java**

```
public class MySocketCreator implements WebSocketCreator {

    private static final String TAG = MySocketCreator.class.getSimpleName();
    private static Log log = new Log(TAG, true);

    private Set<ServerSocket> sockets = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Session> guests = new HashSet<>();
    private ConcurrentHashMap<ServiceUser, ArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest servletUpgradeRequest, ServletUpgradeResponse servletUpgradeResponse) {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(statusCallback);
        sockets.add(socket);
        return socket;
    }


    private OnSessionStatusListener statusCallback = new OnSessionStatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGuestIn(Session session) {


            synchronized (this) {
                guests.add(session);
                Integer totalAgeReduce = users.values()
                        .stream()
                        .map(wsDeviceSessionWrappers -> {
                            return 1;
                        })
                        .reduce(
                                0,
                                (a, b) -> a + b);
                log.debug("onGuestIn() " + "Guests: " + guests.size() + " Registered: " + totalAgeReduce);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUserIn(Session session, ServiceUser user, Device device) {


            synchronized (this) {

                if (guests.contains(session)) guests.remove(session);

                if (!users.containsKey(user)) {
                    users.put(user, new ArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>());
                }
                users.get(user).add(new WSDeviceSessionWrapper(session, device));

                log.debug("onUserIn() " + "Guests: " + guests.size() + " Registered: " + users.size());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void sendResponse(ArrayList<ServiceUser> users, WSResponse response) {
        log.debug("Send message to [" + (users != null ? users.size() : null) + "] current users " + MySocketCreator.this.users.size());
         MySocketCreator.this.users.keySet().forEach(user -> {
               users.forEach(u -> {
                   if (user.equals(u)) {

                       ArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper> wsDeviceSessionWrappers = MySocketCreator.this.users.get(user);
                       new ArrayList<>(wsDeviceSessionWrappers).forEach(wrapper -> {
                               wrapper.getSession().getRemote().sendStringByFuture(response.toJSON());
                           }
                       });

                   }
               });
           });


        }

        @Override
        public void sendResponse(ServiceUser user, WSResponse response, Device excludeDevice) {
                MySocketCreator.this.users.get(user).forEach(wrapper -> {
                    wrapper.getSession().getRemote().sendStringByFuture(response.toJSON());
                });
        }

        @Override
        public void onExit(Session session, ServiceUser user, Device device) {

            synchronized (this) {

                //remove from guest sessions
                if (session != null && guests.contains(session)) guests.remove(session);


                if (user != null && device != null && users.containsKey(user)) {
                    ArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper> wrappers = users.get(user);
                    Iterator<WSDeviceSessionWrapper> iterator = wrappers.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        WSDeviceSessionWrapper wrapper = iterator.next();
                        if (wrapper.getSession() == session || wrapper.getSession().equals(session) && wrapper.getDevice() == device || wrapper.getDevice().equals(device)) {
                            //remove session for current device
                            iterator.remove();

                            //if user does not have session on server
                            //remove him from current server users
                            if (wrappers.size() == 0) {
                                users.remove(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Integer totalRegisteredDevices = users.values()
                        .stream()
                        .map(wsDeviceSessionWrappers -> {
                            return 1;
                        })
                        .reduce(
                                0,
                                (a, b) -> a + b);
                log.debug("onExit() " + "Guests: " + guests.size() + " Registered: " + totalRegisteredDevices);
            }


        }
    };

    public Set<ServerSocket> getSockets() {
        return sockets;
    }

}
```

Логика работы такая:

В классе `MySocketCreator` , при создании нового сокета я передаю туда callback. Далее в самом сокете в событии `onOpen`  я вызываю callback и передаю в него сессию, и эта сессия сохраняется в классе MySocketCreator, после я эту сессию связываю с юзером и девайсом.

Проблема заключается в том что когда я пытаюсь отправить сообщени все пользователям из какого либо `websocket'a` вызвать через callback метод

```
    @Override
    public void sendResponse(ArrayList<ServiceUser> users, WSResponse response) {
    log.debug("Send message to [" + (users != null ? users.size() : null) + "] current users " + MySocketCreator.this.users.size());
       MySocketCreator.this.users.keySet().forEach(user -> {
           users.forEach(u -> {
               if (user.equals(u)) {
                   ArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper> wsDeviceSessionWrappers = MySocketCreator.this.users.get(user);
                   new ArrayList<>(wsDeviceSessionWrappers).forEach(wrapper -> {
                           wrapper.getSession().getRemote().sendStringByFuture(response.toJSON());
                       }
                   });

               }
           });
       });
    }
```

строка                                `wrapper.getSession().getRemote().sendStringByFuture(response.toJSON());`

лочит поток и сервер виснет. Попытка заменить  ее на

`wrapper.getSession().getRemote().sendString(response.toJSON());`

генерирует исключения

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING

org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketException: RemoteEndpoint unavailable, outgoing connection not open
```

Получаеться что  оба варианта не работают и зависанию и некорректно работе сервера. И это все всего лишь при 300 подключениях.

**Вопрос**:каким образом я могу выполнить задачу, отправив всем юзерам сообщения, в чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: Ну видимо один из подключенных клиентов уже отвалился поэтому генерится это исключение. Просто обработайте его. Перед отправкой сообщения нескольким клиентом попробуйте сначала пропинговать их так как описано [тут](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-api-send-message.html), отсеяв отвалившихся товарищей.